# How do integrate dynamic preview of meta tag in whatsapp for Angular 8?

Tags: angular, dynamic, metadata, whatsapp, preview

Actually I want to integrate dynamic link preview for whatsapp, for all my blog pieces. There are many plugins available for angularJS, angular2 and angular 4. But nothing is available for angular 8. Can anyone help me here?
It is for a blog with different slugs in each url i.e for each story, there is a different URL. The headline and image also differs.

Answer (score 0):

Almost every Front-End framework such as Angular is built on the client-side. Meaning the content is non-existing until the site is rendered by the client application.

What you need is a server-side-rendering, which will pre-render your site allowing your blog post image, title or description to be rendered when shared on any platform.

Since you're using Angular I really recommend giving [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

"This guide describes Angular Universal, a technology that renders Angular applications on the server."

Good luck!

Comment: Just to add to this answer, along with SSR, you need to add certain meta tags to your html. This can be done using the Meta service provided by angular. Since you are looking specifically for whatsapp, the following 3 meta tags are must: og:title, og: description and og:image. There are a lot of other considerations for SEO, but that would need to be a separate answer altogether.

Comment: Aaah thank you so much! So this will work in angular 8 too right? I have added meta tags: title and description through   
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: this.DESC[0] });
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'title', content: this.DESC[0] });
So on doing inspect element, I can see these two are being updated in the index file but still no preview shows while sharing on whatsapp.